# How Can I call a function with values that will be executed only once when I have several parameters in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I run pytest with several params:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('signature_algorithm, cipher, name', [
    pytest.param(rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, AES128-GCM-SHA256, "KEY1"),
    pytest.param(rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, AES128-GCM-SHA256, "KEY2"),
    ....
    def test(signature_algorithm, cipher, cert_name, functaion1("data")):
    .....

functaion1(data):
Change file in server (using data value)
```

I need to call the functaion1(data) only once when test starts. How can I achieve this using pytest?

I tried to add functaion1 as parameter in test function but I got syntax error while I add parentheses to the functaion1 (because I want to send a certain value to function1).

Comment: What is the difference between `functaion1` and `function1`?

Comment: you are missing a closing parentheses `)` at the definition of the test `test()`

Answer (score 0):

To call a function only once before the test starts you can use `@pytest.fixture()`.
For this example we can call this a "setup" function but it can have any name you define. Add your `functaion1(data)` function call to the setup function.

I commented out the `functaion1(data)` function call in my example since it is not clear where "data" is coming from.

```
import pytest

class Testonething:

    @pytest.fixture()
    def setup(self):
        print("setting up")
        # functaion1(data)

    def test_one_thing(self, setup):
        print("This is branch1")
        assert True
```